# How to link observer to another file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-models, apiato

I write one observer called userObserver.php and I write one task file called DeleteTask.php which contains DB queries , now I want to make a link with the observer to the DeletTask.php file

Comment: please update you answer with code

Answer (score 0):

In laravel documentation it's mentioned observer is applied for models only.